# Allow empty InputNumber value in Blazor app

Tags: blazor

Have a `EditForm` with different controls (text fields, number fields, checkboxes). All these controls are working fine except number fields that are NOT mandatory.
For example number field for `Age` property:

```
<InputNumber id="age" @bind-Value="Data.Age" class="form-control" />
```

In model it goes like NULLable field (need to allow empty number field on UI):

```
public int? Age { get; set; }
```

But if given field is not filled, I'm getting validation error on Submit:

```
The value '' is not valid for 'Age'.
```

Is `InputNumber` don't allow empty values or am i missing some additional configurations? Which ways i have to solve it (i need to allow empty values for number fields)?

Answer (score 0):

I can't repeat your issue, so there must be something else causing the issue that you aren't including in your question.

Here's a demo page with only a single nullable number field.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnSubmit="this.OnSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <InputNumber class="form-control mb-3" @bind-Value="_model.Age" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Submit</button>
    <ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Age: @(_model.Age?.ToString() ?? "null")</pre>
</div>

@code{
    private EditContext? _editContext;
    private Model _model = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new(_model);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private Task OnSubmit()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public class Model {
        public int? Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Also had a problem with given example. It start working after adding `@rendermode InteractiveServer`. Was also missing `@rendermode` on my page, instead was using `[SupplyParameterFromForm]` on my model.